# Overload operator for int and char in c++

Tags: c++, char, operator-overloading

I want to have a class that can accept assignment from both and int and a string literal.  The string literal, it turns out, must be of type char[].  I actually have a whole lot of data types that are all successfully taken by the assignment operator.  But the compiler gets confused between these two.  I get how interchangeable the char can be with an int, I often use that for quick ascii comparisons.  What I'd like to know is if there's a way to get the compiler to stop trying to send string literals to the int version of the overloaded operator.  None of the other types have this problem, it is only these two that are getting mixed up.

```
    myDataType& operator = (int Right);
    myDataType& operator = (const char &Right);
```

When I try:

```
myDataType Test;

Test = "Hello World.";
```

The compiler tries to interpret the string literal as an int and throws this error:  error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]

Thanks.

Comment: A single char is not a string literal. Use std::string instead.

Comment: I actually have std::string as an accepted input for assignment.  But it doesn't appear to work for string literals.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work? Does it sit on the couch all day? You might want to be a bit more specific with your error descriptions...

Comment: std::string, is technically an extension.  I can create a data type of string and pass that in just fine.  What I'm trying to do is get other programmers to be able to pass in a string literal.  The data type of a string literal is char[].

Comment: @C_Rod, `string` is not an extension. It's been a fully standard part of C++ for a very long time (forever?). And a `string` will always accept a string literal. I think you have a different problem - it is important that you actually give us the error messages, as requested by @Ulrich

Comment: Oh, the actual message is printed in the question.  But it only shows up for char.  if I remove the char version of the operator, it works just fine, through the int operator (producing the wrong value.)  I'm not trying to initialize a string instance with a literal, I'm trying to pass a string literal into my object.  That passes as char.

Comment: To confirm: even if you use `myDataType& operator = (string Right);`, you get the error about "invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ " ?

Comment: No, that doesn't actually produce an error at all.  It just doesn't ever try to get accessed when I assign using a string literal, instead my overloaded int gets called.

Comment: Read this, and apply to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string must be of type `char[]`, then you must have a `[]`, or `*`, in the signature.

```
myDataType& operator = (int Right);
myDataType& operator = (const char *Right);
```

or

```
myDataType& operator = (int Right);
template<size_t N>
myDataType& operator = (const char (&Right)[N]);
```

but, as this is C++, probably just simpler to actually use a `string`

```
myDataType& operator = (int Right);
myDataType& operator = (std::string Right);
```

Comment: The first construct fails, I'm not really sure why, because my constructor uses it and it works just fine, but for the operator, it's not happy.   The second one looks promising, but am I required to know the size of N?

Comment: @C_Rod The compiler deduces `N` from the size of the array, so you don't need to know or care. That's what makes that construct so useful.

Comment: "The first construct fails, I'm not really sure why, "  We can't help you, if you don't give us the error message

Comment: The error message that shows up if I try the first construct here is as follows:  "In member function ‘hexString& hexString::operator=(const char*)’:
hexString.cpp:157:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_string<char>::basic_string(const char**)’"

Comment: Is this an error in my main function or in my implementation of the operator overload?

Comment: How are you calling the assignment?  `myDataType x;   x = .....;`.

 But what is `.....`?

Comment: I'm calling it like this:
myDataType Test;  Test="A literal string";

Comment: (I think I mistakenly interpreted the `**` error. Anyway, I gotta go now, sorry. Good luck!)

Comment: So I never did get the first version to work which I would have liked, but the second one worked great.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the compiler is trying to actually use the constructor as your operator is not of the good type. You should probably give us the full error message, not just the last one.

A string litteral is a `const char *` and not a `const char &`.

I could reproduce it with the following code:struct Foo{

```
struct Foo{
    Foo(){}
    Foo(int test){}
    Foo& operator = (int Right){printf(" =(int)");}
    Foo& operator = (const char Right){printf("=(const char &)");}
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    Foo foo;
    foo = "ttt";
    return 0;
}
```

which gave me the following output :

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:13:9: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Foo' and 'const char [4]')
     foo = "ttt";
         ^
main.cpp:13:9: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:6:10: note: Foo& Foo::operator=(int) <near match>
     Foo& operator = (int Right){printf(" =(int)");}
          ^
main.cpp:6:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char [4]' to 'int'
main.cpp:7:10: note: Foo& Foo::operator=(const char&) <near match>
     Foo& operator = (const char &Right){printf("=(const char *)");}
```

However, the following code is fine :

```
struct Foo{
    Foo(){}
    Foo(int test){}
    Foo& operator = (int Right){printf(" =(int)");}
    Foo& operator = (const char *Right){printf("=(const char *)");}
};
```

If you want the compiler not to convert arguments implicitly, use the explicit keyword like this :

```
struct Foo{
    explicit Foo(int test){}
};
```

This will tell the compiler that this constructor will accept `int`, and only `int` as a parameter type. So pointers won't be using this constructor for example. For more details about it check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228570/implicit-conversion) and [explicit keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/explicit) from cppreference.com

Comment: This is nicely written.  It's a good thought, and I made my constructors explicit just now to help prevent that issue.  It didn't solve the problem, but it's probably good to have in any case.  To confirm, this line works correctly for you?  "Foo& operator = (const char *Right)"  Because this is the construct I would have expected to work, but it fails for me.

Comment: It might be useful to ask another question on stackoverflow, or to edit this question. Your current question has `const char &Right`, and is therefore irrelevant to all the other discussions on these answers. I think you need to pick one form, either `Foo& operator = (const char *Right)` or `Foo& operator = (string Right)`, then edit your question accordingly and work with us to get it working. Give us *all* the relevant code, including where the assingment is actually used. And give us the *first* error message. And put all this in the question

Comment: It does work, you can try it by simply copy pasting my code in a clean main.cpp file. I support what @AaronMcDaid said, edit your question with the full error message and give us more details about your class.